# chrome.tabs.onUpdated fires multiple times in Google Docs

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am working on a Chrome extension that interacts with Google Docs. I have encountered an issue where the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` event is being triggered multiple times for a single tab, even though I have explicitly set `info.status` to `complete` and `all_frames` to `false` in the manifest file. This behavior is causing unexpected results and performance issues in my extension.

Here is the relevant code from my background.js file:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, info, tab) => {
    if (info.status === "complete" && tab.status === "complete"){
        console.log('onUpdated');
    }
});
```

And here is the relevant part of my manifest.json file:

```json
{
    "matches": ["*://docs.google.com/document/*"],
    "js": ["gdocs.js"],
    "all_frames": false,
    "run_at": "document_end"
}
```

As per my understanding, setting all_frames to false should ensure that the event is only triggered for the top-level frame.

Additionally, I have checked `tab.status` are set to `complete` before executing any logic. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: all_frames is for content scripts and it doesn't influence onUpdated, which is not independent. Apparently Chrome switches the tab back into loading mode because of something like maybe iframes that the page loads or it may be a bug in Chrome, which you can report at https://crbug.com.

Comment: @wOxxOm I would really appreciate if could once check opening a google docs page... what is happening in real?